# Windows update freeze blender

Tags: modeling

After updates windows 10, it broke many feature, apps and fps drop. And blender now have weird behaviour. After long idle while blender is still open, my laptop will freeze. While the mouse is still moveable and there's loading indicator on it, no button or mouse click is do-able, force me to shut it down. Usually there will be only icon glitch when it left idle. I haven't found the solution. Any clues to solve this?

Comment: you should try to undo those updates, or try to understand what's happened. blender, as any other program, can't work well on any unstable OS.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because issues seem related to some OS updates gone wrong, somehow, not blender itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Change red spot value to 0 that may help you.

Comment: The problem is still persist.

Comment: nevermind, now it no longer crash. thank you for the help :)